# Force resource download in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, resources, javabeans

Using Spring MVC, I want to force the download of static resources. So I apply the advice given here : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources (15.12.4 mvc:resources).

The goal is to have this configuration :

The software version is given in the resources path, so every time the version change the browsers is forced to download the resources files.

IN the given example, the version is read from a property file. In my case, I want to get this path from a class (service or controller) like myController.getPath(), how can this be achieved in the "beans way" ?

Comment: Have you tried `<resources mapping="#{myController.getPath()}" location=... />`?